# Edit objects inside a listbox?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, listbox

Here is a example screenshot of my 3 listboxes:

[image]

I have basically 3 listboxed (Name, rating, price) that will be used together in a for loop later to perform something in the web app for a game.
For example: Search for Thomas Müller, with rating 86, for a max. price of 10.000

But sometimes I have to add many items to that list. As I do want to avoid that I have to completely delete and re-enter all items, I would like to edit entries. Like for example I would like to change:

Thomas Müller , 86 , 10000
to
Max Mustermann, 100, 999

Is there a way?

Or is there a way how I can delete the value of all 3 lists in one row instead deleting the complete list?

Also as my second question - how would it be possible that I save the listboxes (in a file?) as shown below, so that I could reload a specific setup like this?

Comment: yes, I can use listbox.curseletion()
But in my case I have 3 listboxes, and I would like to delete the row of each box when clicking a button "delete seletced"

Comment: `curselection` gives you an index. You can use the same index in all of the listboxes.

Comment: You can use a `Treeview` to replace the three listboxes.